# Modal not closing using props

Tags: javascript, react-native

Not sure why, but the modal isn't closing when accessing the method from another function. I am able to console log the method in the component, but the method just doesn't work.

This is the main ReviewsScreen.js where the closeModal() function exists

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import ReviewsModal from '../components/ReviewsModal';

class ReviewsScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
  };

  toggleModal() {
    this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => this.toggleModal()}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ReviewsModal closeModal={() => this.toggleModal()} />
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleModal()}>
            <Text> click me </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
  },
});

export default ReviewsScreen;
```

This is the component ReviewsModal.js where I'm trying to run the function

```
import React from 'react';
import {KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import colours from '../constants/colours';

export default class ReviewsModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView styles={styles.container} behaviour="padding">
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{position: 'absolute', top: 64, right: 32}}
          onPress={this.props.closeModal}>
          <Icon name="close" size={24} color={colours.dark} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
  },
});
```

Comment: please check out my answer :) maybe it will help you out

Answer (score 0):

You probable need to bind your function to get the right context.
In your ReviewsScreen constructor add:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
         isModalVisible: false
     }

    
     this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function in constructor like that:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
         isModalVisible: false
     }

    
     this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this)
 }
```

but easier way is just to bind it in the onClick like:

```
<ReviewsModal closeModal={this.toggleModal.bind(this)} />
```

and in child component where you want to trigger it you should use:

```
onPress={() => this.props.closeModal()}>
```

so in parent component you just bind it without executing by `this.toggleModal.bind(this)` but in child component you trigger/execute it by using arrow function `() => this.props.closeModal()`, you have to add `() =>` because it will only run when you click, if you will pass only `this.props.closeModal()` it will trigger it initially when component loads what you don't want to happen